# shopping cart jsp error

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to make a shopping cart and below is the code for display.If the user doesn't have a shopping cart it creates one and displays all the rows such as pip and ean number for the products.

> ```
> <%-- 
>     Document   : DisplayShoppingCart
>     Created on : Jan 24, 2013, 12:48:06 PM
>     Author     : Faiza
> --%>
> <%@ page language="java" import="model.*,java.util.*,java.text.*" %>
>
> <%-- Show the header with the shopping cart image --%>
> <table border="0">
> <tr><td><img src="Drug-basket-icon.png"><td><h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
> </table>
>
> <%
> // Get the current shopping cart from the user's session.
>     ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("ShoppingCart");
>
> // If the user doesn't have a shopping cart yet, create one.
>     if (cart == null)
>     {
>         cart = new ShoppingCart();
>         session.setAttribute("ShoppingCart", cart);
>     }
> // Get the items from the cart.
>     Vector items = cart.getItems();
>
>
> // If there are no items, tell the user that the cart is empty.
>     if (items.size() == 0)
>     {
>         out.println("<h3>Your shopping cart is empty.</h3>");
>     }
>     else
>     {
> %>
> <%-- Display the header for the shopping cart table --%>
> <br>
> <table border=4>
> <tr><th>EAN</th><th>PIP</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Supplier ID</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
> <%
>
>         int numItems = items.size();
>
> // Get a formatter to write out currency values.
>         NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
>
>         for (int i=0; i < numItems; i++)
>         {
>             Item item = (Item) items.elementAt(i);
>
> // Print the table row for the item.
>             out.print("<tr><td>");
>             out.print(item.EAN);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>             out.print(item.PIP);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>             out.print(item.name);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>             out.print(item.description);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>             out.print(item.SupplierID);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>              out.print(item.price);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>              out.print(item.quantity);
>             out.print("</td><td>");
>             out.print(currency.format(item.price));
>
> // Print out a link that allows the user to delete an item from the cart.
>             out.println("</td><td>"+
>                 "<a href=\"/shoppingcart/RemoveItemServlet?item="+
>                 i+"\">Remove</a></td></tr>");
>         }
>     }
> %>
> </table>
> ```

The error I am getting is below i have tried everything but i dont understand what it means

> ```
> pe Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
>
> An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
> Syntax error on token ";", delete this token
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)**
> ```

Comment: Can you please confirm that your imports are fine ?

Comment: An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file. can you open that java file and check out?

Comment: there maybe nothing wrong with your code. Just close your IDE and re-run your project. The problem maybe will go away

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; from import statement.